# Creating my maps in android application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Hey guys i am looking for an application that can navigate inside a mall.We can adopt the idea of inputting our current location through a QR code or by taking a snap of any near landmark(like shop,name boards..),Then we can input where we want go?But the actual problem is How to build a map of the indoor?Can u suggest any such tool to create a map for android phones.Because after creating the map by programming the gyroscope sensor in android for proper routing,because application now knows the source and destination,so i think it can display the shortest route(like GPS),then we can start walking through that path with our phone.Whenever we violates route using gyroscope we can track it.I think it is possible,if we turn left instead of taking right then app will direct us it is a wrong way.But i need help to create the map.Can anyone please suggest any idea?
my email:anishubais@gmail.com
please----

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think that going off of GPS would be inaccurate. If I remember right, GPS is only accurate up to 10 meters or something like that.

Like I said, I might be horribly wrong, I'm just going off of what I remember